# Serialize Field Class

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I need to pass `java.lang.reflect.Field` from one process to another using RMI, but `Field` does not implement `Serializable` interface. how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to pass a Field via RMI.  A Field instance is really a dependent object of a `java.lang.Class` instance, and `Class` objects are not transmissible either.  (And the reason that a `Class` is not transmissible is that it would present all sorts of nasty type checking problems ... considering that a `Class` instance actually denotes a reference type.)

You will need to declare the relevant `Field` field as `transient`.  If you want to transmit the `Field` information, you are probably going to need to pass it in the form of a field name / class name, and then reconstruct the `Field` at the other end in a custom `readObject` method.